# How to ensure that new instance of class can be created only by other class?

Tags: c#, oop

I know that title is little bit to long, so here is my problem .
I've got this class for example:

```
public  class Connection
{
     public static Connection Create()
     {
          return new Connection();
     }            
}
```

I need to ensure that new instances of Connection can be created only by other classes , calling the Create method.The solution must allow classes to inherit from Connection.

Some of the answers I've found is to make class `abstract` or `static` but as I remember, you can't make instance of abstract or static class nor inherit from static.

The other two offered answers is to make `private` or `protected` constructor of Connection class.Well, if constructor is set on private , we can't call him from derived class , but if it is protected, we can .

So , my idea is to make constructor `protected`.Am i right ?Because I found that someone posted making Connection class static is right answer, and that doesn't make any sense .

Comment: you cant. a class can always be instantiated inside itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `static` and `abstract` are out for the reasons that you outlined in your question. The way to let other classes inherit from yours, while prohibiting direct instantiation is to make the constructor `protected`. Keep in mind, however, that an inheriting class can choose to allow its own constructor to be `public`, thus circumventing your protection.

In general, though, a class should be designed either for inheritance or for instantiation, but not for both purposes at the same time. A better design would be as follows:

```
public abstract class Connection {
    protected Connection();
    public static Connection Create() {
        return new DefaultConnection();
    }
}
internal sealed class DefaultConnection : Connection {
    public DefaultConnection() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Classes from outside can inherit `Connection`, but they cannot instantiate it because it's `abstract`. Your code, on the other hand, can create instances of `DefaultConnection`, which is hidden from everybody else because it is `internal`.

Answer (score 0):

If you create it as a child class in main class,  set the constructor to take a parameter which is generated internally in main class and verified using a private method in main class.

This way no external class can't instantiate the child class without throwing an exception.